# How to integrate $\iint_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x+y)dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

So I was bored, and decided to find the areas of some functions. After a while, I decided to do$$\int_Df(x,y)dxdy$$ where $$f(x,y)=\sin(x+y),D=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2,-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le \dfrac\pi2,-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\right\}$$ which I thought that I might be able to integrate. Here is my attempt at doing so:$$\begin{align}\int_Df(x,y)dxdy\implies&\iint_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x+y)dxdy\implies\iint_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)dxdy\\\implies&\iint_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\cos(y)dxdy+\iint_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\sin(y)dxdy\\\implies&2\left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}0\cdot\cos(y)dy-\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(y)dy\right)\\\implies&-2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(y)dy=-2\cdot(0-0)=-2\cdot0=0\end{align}$$

---

#### My question

---

Did I evaluate the function over the domain correctly, or what could I do to attain the correct area?

Comment: You should not calculate at all but use some thought to see that the area has as many positive parts as negatives, so it has to be 0, but this of cause is also the result of your  right calculation

Comment: Correct answer. Are you familiar with integrating odd functions? It can be proven that if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ then $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx =0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my evaluation of the area is overall correct, I did mess up by not showing my full thought process, which could lead to confusion<sup>[$1$]</sup>. Here's how you could more easily calculate the area with a complete thought process:

---

Here are the derivatives of $f(x)=\sin(x)$ from $-4$ to $4$, not including the $0$th derivative (For every $(-n)$th derivative, this implies the $n$th integral of a function $f(x)$ with respect to its dummy variable):$$\begin{align}f^{(-4)}(x)=&\;\sin(x)\\f^{(-3)}(x)=&\;\cos(x)\\f^{(-2)}(x)=&\;-\sin(x)\\f^{(-1)}(x)=&\;-\cos(x)\\f'(x)=&\;\cos(x)&\\f''(x)=&\;-\sin(x)\\f'''(x)=&\;-\cos(x)\\f^{(4)}(x)=&\;\sin(x)\end{align}$$

---

---

Now, looking at my steps used to integrate $\sin(x+y)$ over $\left[-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right]$ on both the $x$-axis and $y$-axis, we see that I split up the integral into $I=I_1+I_2$ with<sup>[1]</sup>$$\begin{align}I_1=&\;\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(y)dy\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)dx\\I_2=&\;\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)dx\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(y)dy\end{align}$$Now on how to evaluate $I_1$ (our left hand side):

---

With$$g(x)=h'(x)=\cos(x)\implies\int h(x)dx=-g(x),g'(x)=-h(x)$$we have$$I_1=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}g(y)dy\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}h(x)dx$$$$\implies-\left[h(y)\right]_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}\left[g(x)\right]_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}$$$$=-1\cdot(1+1)\cdot(0-0)=-2\cdot(0-0)=0-0=0$$Now, for evaluating $I_2$, we have$$I_2=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}g(x)dx\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}h(y)dy$$$$\implies-[h(x)]_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}[g(y)]_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}$$$$=-1\cdot(1+1)\cdot(0-0)=-2\cdot(0-0)=0-0=0$$So now we have$$I=I_1+I_2=0+0=0$$$$\therefore I=\int_Df(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x+y)=0$$

---

#### Notes

---

<sup>[$1$]</sup>Sorry if this isn't allowed under the definition of an "acceptable" answer. It really would have been weird to edit my question $2$ days later, and I just wanted to avoid any confusion that might have arisen.